# Compactness of complex projective space, references

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, complex-geometry, projective-space

I know that the complex projective space is compact, but I have to justify it for my thesis, so I need references for this fact. I search the web, but I didn't find anything. Does someone knows a book (or an article) where this fact in shown?

Thanks

Comment: If you want an explicit reference, you could use Griffiths & Harris, _Principles of algebraic geometry_, Chapter 0.2. They say: "$\mathbb{P}^n$ is compact, since we have a continuous surjective map from the unit sphere in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ to $\mathbb{P}^n$."

Comment: thanks. that's exactly what I was searching for

Answer (score 4):

The projection map $\pi\colon\mathbb{S}^{2n+1}\to \mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{C})$ is continuous and surjective, since $\mathbb{S}^{2n+1}$ is compact, we have that: $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{C})=\pi(\mathbb{S}^{2n+1})$ is compact. I think that you can find a similar argument in "Topologia" of M. Manetti or "Geometria 2" of E. Sernesi.